# Dropping and creating indexes using dynamic sql (sp_executesql)

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where I am trying to create and maintain indexes on 30+ databases which are regularly restored from backups.

I have the stored procedure below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Create_Index 
    @DATABASE sysname 

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DROPFIRSTINDEX nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @DROPSECONDINDEX nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @CREATEFIRSTINDEX nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @CREATESECONDINDEX nvarchar(MAX)


    SET @DROPFIRSTINDEX = 

    N'IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[sys].[indexes] WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[dbo].[FirstTable]'') AND name = N''IX_FIRSTINDEX'')
    DROP INDEX [IX_FIRSTINDEX] ON ' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[dbo].[FirstTable] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )'

    SET @DROPSECONDINDEX =

    N'IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[sys].[indexes] WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[dbo].[SecondTable]'') AND name = N''IX_SECONDINDEX'')
    DROP INDEX [IX_SECONDINDEX] ON ' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[dbo].[SecondTable] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )'

    SET @CREATEFIRSTINDEX = 

    N'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FIRSTINDEX] ON ' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[dbo].[FirstTable] 
    (
        [DateTime] ASC
    )WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
         , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
         , DROP_EXISTING = OFF
         , ONLINE = OFF
         , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
         , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]'

    SET @CREATESECONDINDEX =

    N'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SECONDINDEX]
    ON ' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + N'.[dbo].[SecondTable] ([CustomerID],[SessionID])
    INCLUDE ([Type])'

    EXEC sp_executesql @DROPFIRSTINDEX 

    EXEC sp_executesql @DROPSECONDINDEX 

    EXEC sp_executesql @CREATEFIRSTINDEX 

    EXEC sp_executesql @CREATESECONDINDEX 

    RETURN

END
GO
```

This works fine and drops and re-creates the indexes, however as they grow each iteration is taking longer and longer.
Is there any way this can be changed over to skip the database if they already contain the appropriate indexes?
I've tried thinking through a way to do this but have drawn a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already checking to see if the index exists, then dropping it if it does. So just extend it with IF ELSE logic

```
IF EXISTS...
   SET @FirstCommand='DROP INDEX...'
ELSE
   SET @FirstCommand='CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX...'
```

Then you only need to do one sp_executesql for each index (instead of one drop and one create).

Comment: I need to run the `IF EXISTS` within the dynamic sql as I have to specify one of the many database names, how can I run it within the dynamic sql but keep the IF/ELSE structure? I already tried something similar a while ago but I get an error: `Index 'IX_FIRSTINDEX' already exists` when it compiles the dynamic query.

Comment: Something like the following maybe? SET @FirstCommand='IF EXISTS... DROP INDEX... ELSE CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX...'

Comment: If it exists I don't want to drop it, I want to only create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Of course- posted previous comment too quickly. That's actually easier: SET @FirstCommand='IF NOT EXISTS... CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX...'

Comment: This worked when I tried it again, I must have had a syntax problem previously, appreciate your time.